# How to add a class to a nav ul li a using jQuery when the nav is in an external file?

Tags: jquery, class, external, nav

I have a dashboard with a navigation on the left side. The navigation is declared on an external file named nav.html.

In every page I load the navigatoin using jQuery using this:

```
  <script>
     $(function () {
        $.get("nav.html", function (data) {
        $("nav").append(data);
        });
     });
  </script>
```

Now I try to add a class on the active a element and I didn't find a way...

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: how are you adding the class ? using event delegation will work I guess

Comment: What do you mean by 'active'? Active as in the `href` of that link is the page you are currently viewing, or active as in the cursor is hovered over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show the structure of `nav.html`, but I assume you do know which element should be active. One possible approach:

```
$.get("nav.html", function(navHtml) {
  var $navHtml = $(navHtml);
  var $activeLink = $navHtml.find('a[href="' + getActiveLink() + '"]'); // for example
  $activeLink.addClass('active');
  $("nav").append($navHtml);
});
```

The point is creating a jQuery object wrapping an HTML element not yet attached to `window.document` - this element is created from parsing `html` file. You can process this object the same way you do the 'real ones' from DOM - in particular, find a specific element with `.find()` method, then add a specific class to that element with `.addClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

After you append, you should be able to modify the elements. BTW, you can use `.load()` to combine `$.get` and `.html()`. In its callback function, `this` will be the `nav` element that you loaded the HTML into, so you can use this to find DOM elements there.

```
$("nav").load("nav.html", function() {
    $(this).find("a").addClass("active");
});
```